# query all item from second table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id int primary key auto_increment,....);
CREATE TABLE table2 (id int primary key auto_increment,   
                     table1_id int foreign key references table1(id) on delete cascade,
                     item text not null,....);
```

I would like to know how I can get all items from table two given the id of table1. Also some of the items are written in Uniode text, I can't use the query select from command prompt because I only see odd characters in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, table1_id, item 
FROM table2 
WHERE table2.table1_id=table1.id
```

Comment: you can also use `SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.table1_id=table1.id` if you have more columns in the second table